# gvim how to move window to bottom right?

Tags: vim

Say I have a gvim window with 3 sub windows in it, all vertically beside each other, so three columns.

how would I move the second column to the bottom right so that the two columns on the left are arranged one on top of another (horizontally split) while the third column remains the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately that's not super easy… you've got to do it with a couple of motions. If you start with:

```
+---+---+---+
| A | B | C |
+---+---+---+
```

And you want to end with:

```
+---+---+
| A |   |
+---+ C |
| B |   |
+---+---+
```

You'd need to:

1. Focus `B`
2. Use `<c-w> J` to move it to the bottom
3. Focus `C`
4. Use `<c-w> L` to send it to the right